# play multiple files as one in video html tag

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm trying to play multiple video files in one html player as if it's a single file.

For now, I found a script to play videos one after the other in the same player :

```
<video id="videoPlayer" autoplay autobuffer controls></video>

<script>
var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer')

var vArray = [
    "my-first-video.mp4",
    "my-second-video.mp4",
    "my-thrid-video.mp4",
]

videoPlayer.src = vArray[0]

i = 1
videoPlayer.onended = function(){
    if (i < vArray.length) {
        videoPlayer.src = vArray[i]
       i++
    }
}
</script>
```

The problemes are :

- there is a small cut between each video
- the progress bar is not global for all the videos but for each one of them

The point is that users don't realise that there are many videos playing in the payer.

How can I manage to make this ? Is it possible only with the video HTML tag ? Or are there video player to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: I would be surprised if there was a way to avoid that small 'cut' as you say since you are dealing with multiple video files.  The progress bar issue should be fixable, although I don't see your implementation of that.  But, you should be able to use the vArray.length to manage the progress bar, or the actual time of the combined videos.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible for some web video players to play parts of a file as if it's a single one. For example : http://filmstreamvk.info/series/kojak-1973-saison-2/Episode/10-VF if you try to get the video file with tools like Download Helper, it's impossible : it does'nt detect a whole video file but a lot of smalls ones. So if anybody got an idea of how to do this, with a player or with the html video tag, it would be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to achieve what I wanted to do, I directly merge the videos together with ffmpeg using this module: https://github.com/ArsalanDotMe/VideoStitch

Answer (score 0):

Try This :`
This is an HTML code in which you can add more than one video at a time on your page.

```
<video width="400" controls autoplay> 
    <source src="my-third-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video width="400" controls autoplay> 
    <source src="my-second-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video width="400" controls> 
    <source src="my-third-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not what I want to do :)

Answer (score 0):

You can join the files as a temporary or permanent output.mp4 file and then run that video on your script. If the files are small, it takes a few seconds. I have join huge files, and did not take too long.

For ffmpeg you can create a list from your array and issue the command

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

List must be with this format on plain txt (you can create the file in your server using your array):

```
file my-first-video.mp4
file my-second-video.mp4
file my-thrid-video.mp4
```

if you don not want to create a list, you can create directly from files on a folder, it goes from first mp4 listed with "ls" and ends with the last mp4 found.

```
ffmpeg $(for f in *.mp4 ; do echo -n "-i $f "; done) -filter_complex "$(i=0 ; for f in *.mp4 ; do echo -n "[$i:v] [$i:a] " ; i=$((i+1)) ; done && echo "concat=n=$i:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]")" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

Then you can use that output.mp4 simulate one only file without users figure it out. Hope it works for you Regards.