# Playing multiples videos as one in HTML video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm trying to play severals segments videos as one on html player.

There is a very similar question : [play multiple files as one in video html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237652/play-multiple-files-as-one-in-video-html-tag) but answers didn't help me because i can't merge my segments video in one big video (segments are stored in S3 and I want to play them directly on a website)

Here is my code :

```
<video id="videoPlayer" autoplay width="700" controls></video>

<script>
var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer')

var vArray = [
    "output000.mp4",
    "output001.mp4",
    "output002.mp4",
]

videoPlayer.src = vArray[0]

i = 1
videoPlayer.onended = function(){
    if (i < vArray.length) {
        videoPlayer.src = vArray[i]
       i++
    }
}
</script>
```

Problems are :

- the progress bar is not global
- there is a little cut when changing segment (this is not very important for me, but if there is a way to avoid that, it will be great)

I didn't found any solution or another webplayer to solve this. Is it possible to do this on HTML player ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Léandre, did you get your answer for this?

Comment: Hi @Sky, I don't remember everything i did for this project, but i used DASH to play segments : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/DASH_Adaptive_Streaming_for_HTML_5_Video . You have to do a little preprocessing for segments to create a mpd manifest, but it's very efficiency

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Léandre. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert mp4 to HLS first.

Use ffmpeg. [Document](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#hls-2)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but HLS is not supported in Chrome right ? And I want to avoid video processing (with my original mp4 files)